# Invalid template file in a custom module

Tags: magento2, order-status, custom-template, payment-banktransfer

**Issue:**

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid
>   template file: 'Toogas_Easypay::info/multibanco.phtml' in module:
>   'Toogas_Easypay' block's name: 'multibanco\info_0'

**Layout Location:**

> public_html/app/code/Toogas/Easypay/view/frontend/templates/info/multibanco.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * @var \Magento\Payment\Block\Info $block
 * @see \Magento\Payment\Block\Info
 */
$specificInfo = $block->getSpecificInformation();
$title = $block->escapeHtml($block->getMethod()->getTitle());
?>
<dl class="payment-method">
    <dt class="title"><?php /* @noEscape */ echo $title; ?></dt>
<?php if($specificInfo): ?>
    <dd class="content" style="border: solid 1px #ddd;padding-bottom: 12px;">
        <table class="data">
            <tr><td style="height:64px;" colspan="2"><img src="<?php echo $block->getLogoSrc() ?>" style="height:64px;"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Entity'))?>:</strong></td><td ><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($specificInfo['entity'])?></td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Reference'))?>:</strong></td><td ><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($specificInfo['reference'])?></td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Amount'))?>:</strong></td><td ><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($specificInfo['amount'])?></td></tr>
        </table>
    </dd>
<?php endif; ?>
</dl>
<?php echo $block->getChildHtml()?>
```

Comment: share the code where you set this template.

Comment: Check if is there any error in phtml file. I have face same issue and I have error in phtml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact problem, the reason is because this module only supports magento 2.0.* This was from an actual phone conversation we had with them today.
However after a couple hours of digging though the code I found the solution!

Copy the file **app/code/Toogas/Easypay/view/adminhtml/templates/multibanco.phtml** to a new folder :
**app/code/Toogas/Easypay/view/adminhtml/templates/info/multibanco.phtml**
And that's it!